# Avoid the use of value in annotations when its the only element

Tags: java, spring, jpa, pmd

"UnnecessaryAnnotationValueElement: Avoid the use of value in annotations when its the only element"

@Query(value = "SELECT t FROM IntraPaymentTransaction t WHERE exchangeBuyAmount.currency <> exchangeSellAmount.currency")

I use this query in my repository but PMD return "UnnecessaryAnnotationValueElement:    Avoid the use of value in annotations when its the only element"
DO you have any idea?

Comment: Did you try to search the internet for the error message? https://pmd.github.io/pmd/pmd_rules_java_codestyle.html#unnecessaryannotationvalueelement

Comment: The PMD message is clear. Remove the value from annotation definition. Write only @Query("SELECT...")

Answer (score 0):

When value is the only element, it doesn't have to be specified.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t FROM IntraPaymentTransaction t WHERE exchangeBuyAmount.currency <> exchangeSellAmount.currency")
```

can be replaced by:

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM IntraPaymentTransaction t WHERE exchangeBuyAmount.currency <> exchangeSellAmount.currency")
```

Comment: yes I missed it thank you